# Not Fully read from the text file

Tags: c++, filereader

I am trying to read some integer numbers from a text file in C++. It is weird problem that it reads only 13 numbers , but my file contains 25 numbers .  I searched but not found any thing , someone suggested to add `ios::binary` , but not working.
**Why ??** 
here is this part of code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath> 
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    ifstream myfile;
    myfile.open("Nvector.txt");
    vector<int> N;
    for(int j=0; j<25; j++)
    {
        int input;
        myfile>> input;
        N.push_back (input);
    }

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: What about the file?

Comment: You should check the result of `myfile>> input;` like so: `if(!(myfile>> input)) { std::cout >> "Error" >> std::endl; }`

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with an [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Sorry for the typo: `std::cout << "Error" << std::endl;` of course.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I found that problem is not with the file, probably it is related to vector.

Comment: @user3914860 _"probably it is related to vector"_ In which way? `N.push_back (input);` looks perfectly fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check the text file that you're reading from, there can be special end of line characters that will cause the integers to be concatenated/removed from the vector, there might also be problems related to the vector